# Can't get my alerts working properly with a calendar

Tags: javascript, button, calendar

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["confirm"].value;
  if (x != "") {
    alert("Thank you for your booking! We look forward to seeing you on soon!");
  } else {
    alert("Please enter a date for your booking!");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="confirm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <input type="date" id="booking" name="booking">
  <input type="submit" value="Book Now">
</form>
```

I want the alert to say thank you for the booking with any date entered, and please input a date if the box is empty.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function validateForm() {
  var date = booking.value;
  if (date) {
    alert(`Thank you for your booking! We look forward to seeing you on ${date}!`);
  } else {
    alert("Please enter a date for your booking!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="confirm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <input type="date" id="booking" name="booking" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Book Now">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```js
function validateForm() {
        var x = document.querySelector('#booking').value;
        if (x) {
            alert("Thank you for your booking! We look forward to seeing you on soon!");
        } else {
            alert("Please enter a date for your booking!");
        }
    }
```

```html
<form name="confirm" onsubmit="validateForm()" method="post">
        <input type="date" id="booking" name="booking">
        <input type="submit" value="Book Now">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

2 pointers:

1) Your selector is wrong. You need the value of date input which has id `booking`.

2) You don't necessarily need to compare with empty string, just do `if (x)`.

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.getElementById("booking").value;
    if (x) {
       alert("Thank you for your booking! We look forward to seeing you on soon!");
    } else {
       alert("Please enter a date for your booking!");  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cause you choose the forms Element, so you should select the "booking" element in form Element.

Can see below. and read this doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms

```js
    function validateForm(e) {
      var x = document.forms["confirm"];
      let formData = x.elements[0].value;

      if (formData != "") {
        alert("Thank you for your booking! We look forward to seeing you on soon!");
      } else {
        alert("Please enter a date for your booking!");
      }
    }
```

```html
<form name="confirm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <input type="date" id="booking" name="booking">
  <input type="submit" value="Book Now">
</form>
```